# Send more data than only the form (node.js post)

Tags: javascript, node.js, forms, post, webforms

Is it possible when someone submits a form it sends additional things instead of only the input fields? In my case it would be the username.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can always intercept the submission of the form and handle it manually. In fact that's what you should do anyway if you want to validate the form fields beforehand.

The logic is pretty straightforward. You attach an `onsubmit` event listener to the form. Prevent the auto submission by calling `preventDefault()` on the event. Then collect the values from all the fields, do the validation (*if email is in the proper format, if passwords match, etc.*), add arbitrary accompanying properties to the object and post the whole thing to the server via ajax post request.

Since you are asking that kind of question I will recommend to use some JS library to make it easier, `jQuery` is perfect for such case:

```js
$('#myForm').on('submit', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();

  const $form = $(this); 
  const method = $form.attr('method');
  const action = $form.attr('action')
  const fields = $form.serializeArray();
  
  fields.push({
    name: 'username',
    value: 'myUsername'
  })
  
  const queryStr = $.param(fields);
 
  $[method](action, queryStr)
  .done(function() {
    // submission was successful - do something, refresh page for exmaple
  })
  .fail(function() {
    // submission failed
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<form id="myForm" method="post" action="/handle.php">
  My name is: <input type="text" name="fname" /><br />
  <label for="agree">I agree</label> <input type="checkbox" name="agree" value="1" /><br />
  <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Of course `/handle.php` is a fake endpoint so submission here obviously won't work.